Sudden problem with event_time when sending firebase message
I have a service sending messages to FCM using C# .NET8.
Starting from sunday evening no messages are sent and the following error is reported

Invalid value at 'message.android.notification.event_time' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Timestamp), Field 'event_time', Invalid time format: Failed to parse input

Problem is that event_time is not part of my message and never has been.
Messages are initialized like this:
            var message = new Message()
            {
               Notification = new Notification
               {
                  Title = title,
                  Body = bodyparts[0]
               },
               Android = new AndroidConfig()
               {
                  Priority = Priority.High,
                  Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                  {
                     Sound = "default",
                  },
               },
               Apns = new ApnsConfig()
               {
                  Aps = new Aps()
                  {
                     ContentAvailable = true,
                     Sound = "default",
                  },
               },
               Token = to
            };


I have tried to initialize notification like this
                  Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                  {
                     Sound = "default",
                     EventTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                  },


but errormessage is the same.
Can someone please help?
I have customers relying on the messageservice...
Regards Klaus

Would this solution help? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/issues/381#issuecomment-2084843924 . Or a solution couple of comments above, to use older version 2.2.0 of Firebase SDK

Seems that it is the nuget package FirebaseAdmin I have used for a couple of years.
I fixed the problem by forking the repo, and change the attribute
[JsonProperty("event_time")]
private string EventTimeString

to
[JsonIgnore]
private string EventTimeString
in file AndroidNotification.cs
A quite brutal solution, but I dont need the event_time parameter in my project.
Sigh...
